# Updating a wiki page name & title will not update its friendly url accordingly

Tags: navigation, publishing-site, url, publishing, managed-navigation

I have created an enterprise wiki site collection inside SharePoint server 2013, and I have defined managed navigation inside the Global Navigation as follow:-

[image]

Then I created a new wiki page named Test , where the physical url will be:-

```
http://***/sites/testf/Pages/test.aspx
```

And the friendly url will be :-

```
http://***/sites/testf/test
```

After that I edit the wiki page name & title to be `TestUpdated` instead of `test`, but now I will get the page physical url as :-

```
http://***/sites/testf/Pages/testupdated.aspx
```

But the problem is that its friendly url will not get updated accordingly, and it will still referencing the old name:-

```
http://***/sites/testf/test
```

So why the friendly url did not get the new name and title , is there a reason for this?
Can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: Because the friendly URL is based on terms, and the name of the terms (not the page). So you also need to rename the term if you rename a page

Comment: @RobertLindgren but seems this is a long process for end users to do , they will expect renaming a wiki page will do all of these. For example when i first deploy the site we realize that when updating the wiki page name its title will NOT get updated,, , so i wrote a workflow that will update the wiki page title when its name is changed.... but now there is also the friendly urls ,,,

Comment: @RobertLindgren to be honest i am starting to feel that having friendly urls is just adding more headache to me ,, as till now i am unable to feel their real benefits , of course the only benefit is that accessign something such as "http://abc/test" is more friendly than accessing "http://abc/pages/test.aspx", but other than this where is the real benefit of friendly urls??in all ways asking end user to update the term when they rename a wiki page is not an option that i can consider.. what do u think ?

Comment: I think you need to think about what you are trying to achive. When we work with friendly URLS (managed navigation) we do this because there also is a term structure that is used for tagging documents or something that should be visible based on the current pages friendly url (term). Otherwise, it is a bit more tricky to work with. Also note that using a termset gives you the possiblity to create a "virtual" hierarchy of tha pages wihout subsites

Comment: @RobertLindgren you mentioned ">>we do this because there also is a term structure that is used for tagging documents or something that should be visible based on the current pages friendly url (term).<<" but regarding tagging documents , i use different approach as inside my current wiki pages i added some managed metadata columns which are used to tag the wiki page , where each managed metadata column is linked to a term set ,, is this what you are talking about by  ">>we do this because there also is a term structure that is used for tagging documents <<" or they are different things ?

Comment: We do that in another way

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you adivce more, what do "that" refers to ? and which is the approach you use ?

Comment: Not really, since it is not in scope of this question and also is a lengthy architectual explanation

Comment: @RobertLindgren i mean you implement tagging documents using managed navigation rather than using managed metadata columns?

Comment: We tag documents with the same termset as we use for managed navigation, in short.

Comment: @RobertLindgren but what if you need to add more than one managed metadat column inside the wiki page ,, then you can not have these defined in the managed navigation ,,

Comment: Nope, then you do not used managed navigation, but activates the (enterprise only) managed metadata navigation in the actual pages library

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes this what i am doing currently. i have activated the "metadata navigation and filtering" site features. then inside the library i define the metadata navigation setting. so i can filter wiki pages  , by clicking on terms inside the term tree... so in my case i think metadata navigation and filtering inside my library is what best suites my case,, even if i do not have friendly urls...

Comment: @RobertLindgren i know this might be out of the original question, but you mentioned that the metadata navigation and filtering feature is available on the Enterprise only license,, while our customer is having "SharePoint Server with Standard Client Access License " and the feature is available . so i think this feature requires to have SP server not SP foundation regardless of the SP server has a standard or enterprise license ?? is this correct ?